# How to gather not tensor object in torch.distributed?

Tags: pytorch

What I want to do is gather not tensor object in torch.distributed. For example, I launch job using torchrun and have these dicts on 4 ranks:

```
P 0: {0: 1}
P 2: {2: 1}
P 4: {4: 1}
P 6: {6: 1}
P 8: {8: 1}
All: {}
```

what I want is

```
P 0: {0: 1}
P 2: {2: 1}
P 4: {4: 1}
P 6: {6: 1}
P 8: {8: 1}
All: {0: 1, 2: 1, 4: 1, 6: 1, 8: 1}
```

Is there any way to do this?

I have tried Manager, but not working

Answer (score 0):

You can use `all_gather_object` from `torch.distributed`. You can find the documentation [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/distributed.html#torch.distributed.all_gather_object). Basically this allows you to gather any pickeable object, the examples are pretty clear in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

I simulated a scenario in which I want to gather the predictions (may be logits) and labels, in order to calculate some metrics like AP, ecc.

```
import os
import time
import torch
import torch.distributed as dist

if __name__ == "__main__":
    '''
    Simulate gathering predictions labels (Xi) and Predictions (Xi + 1) from all the GPUs using python pickable objects.
    In this way, we don't actually need to pad the tensors to the same size, which is a requirement for the all_gather function.

    Moreover, we are sure that the tensors are gathered in the same order as the ranks (because we the key to output list is the rank itself)
    '''
    
    dist.init_process_group("nccl", init_method="env://")
    
    lrank = int(os.environ["LOCAL_RANK"])
    torch.cuda.set_device(lrank)
    rank = dist.get_rank()


    if rank == 0:
        labels = torch.arange(1,3, device="cuda")
        predictions = torch.arange(2,4, device="cuda")
    else:
        labels = torch.arange(10,end=22, device="cuda")
        predictions = torch.arange(11,end=23, device="cuda")
    
    all_labels = {rank: labels.tolist()}
    all_predictions = {rank: predictions.tolist()}

    print(f"Rank: {rank} - Labels: {labels}")
    print(f"Rank: {rank} - Predictions: {predictions}")


    output_list_labels = [torch.zeros_like(torch.empty(1)) for _ in range(dist.get_world_size())]
    output_list_predictions = [torch.zeros_like(torch.empty(1)) for _ in range(dist.get_world_size())]
    

    if rank == 1:
        time.sleep(2) # simulate delay

    dist.all_gather_object(output_list_labels, all_labels)
    dist.all_gather_object(output_list_predictions, all_predictions)

    
    if rank == 0:
        print()
        print(f"Gather all the tensors at rank {rank}!")
        print("Labels: ", output_list_labels)
        print("Predictions: ", output_list_predictions)

        # take preds and labels from the same rank
        # ...
    
    dist.destroy_process_group()
```

Run with the following command:

```
torchrun --rdzv_backend c10d --rdzv_endpoint localhost:0 --nnodes 1  --nproc_per_node 2 FILE.py
```